# Problem with cusom Dialog for ProgressDialog

Tags: android, dialog, textview, nullpointerexception

I have a LoginDialog called from Activity. In LoginDialog  I am trying to open another Dialog (mProgressDlg) to indicate the progress. In mProgressDlg layout I have 2 TextView. I get `NullPointerException` on `setText()` of any of those `TextView`.

LoginDialog  :

```
    private Dialog mProgressDlg;
     private TextView mMessage, mprogTitle, mProgMessage;
public LoginDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    ld = null;
    init();
    }
private void init() {
    this.setContentView(R.layout.user_pass_dialog);

    mMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    mMessage.setText("Loaded ");

    // ProgressDialog
    mProgressDlg = new Dialog(mContext);
    mProgressDlg.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
    mProgTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText_progressDlg);
    mProgMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_progressDlg);
    // On below 2 lines, I get NPE.
    mProgTitle.setText("Hello");
    mProgMessage.setText("Good Day");
}
```

progressDialog.xml

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/titleText_progressDlg" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/message_progressDlg" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></TextView>
```

LogCat :

```
04-06 14:54:29.087: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 14:54:29.087: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(379):     at orange.android.vpn.LoginDialog.init(LoginDialog.java:88) ***// THIS IS mProgTitle.setText("Hello");***
04-06 14:54:29.087: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(379):     at orange.android.vpn.LoginDialog.<init>(LoginDialog.java:50)  ***// THIS IS CALLING init() FROM CONSTRUCTOR***
```

Can anyone help me know, why am I getting this `NullPointerException` in `init()` while accessing `mProgTitle` and/or `mProgMessage`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mProgressDlg.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);

    mProgTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText_progressDlg);
```

should be

```
 mProgressDlg.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);

    mProgTitle = (TextView) mProgressDlg.findViewById(R.id.titleText_progressDlg);
```

because you are accessing components in the dialog layout. just findViewById is used in as a function in activity because you: with setContentView({layout}) you set activity's layout and access components with findViewById, the same for dialog you type dialog.setContentView and you access components the samo diloag.findViewById

Comment: Thank You. Hmm, I didn't realize that point. Was under the impression if we can see the list of all id's then it should be accessible anywhere, anyway. Thanks.

Comment: How to avoid closing the dialog on Escape key ? It shouldn't close untill application commands it. For that on device, what keyListener KEYS should be handled ?

Comment: you should do like this

`mProgressDlg.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
   
   public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
     return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
  });`

Comment: [creating dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

this is how you can create spinning dialogs